# Ftp fails to transfer file to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have added a User and i can see the files

```
useradd -m -d /var/www/html USERNAME
```

But i cannot transfer any file to ftp, it returns me:

```
Error:  /var/www/html/wp-content/Black Panther_1080p.mp4: open for write: permission denied
Error:  File transfer failed
```

Answer (score 0):

change permission cmd. hope this help you.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/movies/
```

Comment: Can you set write permission 755